# Animated mask and hide circle on hover with css

Tags: css, geometry

I wanna make info box with this design.

[image]

This design is important to me. When mouse is over the circle, I need some animation and transform design to this...

[image]

[**jsFiddle Example :**](https://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/ynzwjc34/)

```css
.wrapper{
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
}
.mask {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
    clip-path: circle(80px at 50% 50%);
    position: relative;
}
.mask:hover {
    clip-path:  circle(100% at 50% 50%);
}
.wrapper:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    top: calc(-50% - 83px);
    left: calc(50% - 83px);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background:transparent;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #aaa;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="map-canvas" class="mask">
    
    </div>
</div>
```

But I don't know how to hide the circle.

[image]

Is there any solution how to make and hide that circle with border and shadow ?

Comment: how's something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ynzwjc34/3/

Comment: Thank you, yeah. It works to :)

Comment: Cool! You're welcome, submitted as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use transition and opacity for `wrapper:after`

You would want to transparent pseudo element `after` on hover and target it with `.wrapper:hover:after`.

```css
.wrapper{
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
}
.mask {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
  clip-path: circle(80px at 50% 50%);
  position: relative;
}
.mask:hover {
  clip-path:  circle(100% at 50% 50%);
}
.wrapper:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  top: calc(-50% - 83px);
  left: calc(50% - 83px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:transparent;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #aaa;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity:1;
  transition: all 0.5s forwards ;   /*added */
}
.wrapper:hover:after{
  opacity:0 ;                      /*added */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="map-canvas" class="mask">

  </div>
</div>
```

also if you want some animation on hover out you can use bellow code:

```css
.wrapper{
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
}
.mask {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
  clip-path: circle(80px at 50% 50%);
  position: relative;
}
.mask:hover {
  clip-path:  circle(100% at 50% 50%);
}
.wrapper:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  top: calc(-50% - 83px);
  left: calc(50% - 83px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:transparent;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #aaa;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in ;


}
.wrapper:hover:after{
  opacity:0 ;
  transition: all 0.5s forwards ; /* added */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="map-canvas" class="mask">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just unset the `border` and `box-shadow` on `:hover` and `transition` that change, too, if you want.

```css
.wrapper{
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
}
.mask {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  background-size: cover;
  clip-path: circle(80px at 50% 50%);
  position: relative;
}
.mask, .wrapper:after {
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}
.wrapper:hover .mask {
  clip-path:  circle(100% at 50% 50%);
}
.wrapper:hover:after {
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.wrapper:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  top: calc(-50% - 83px);
  left: calc(50% - 83px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:transparent;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #aaa;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="map-canvas" class="mask">
  </div>
</div>
```